# Generated save SQL for an association class mapped by GORM has correct column name in SELECT clause, but incorrect one in WHERE clause

Tags: hibernate, grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, grails-2.4

I have a many-to-many relationship that has its own association class to represent the join table, with a composite ID of the associations. The join table is as simple as it gets, with just two columns, each of which are a foreign key to each table in the many-to-many relationship:

> Table LOCATION_REASON has Columns: LOCATION_ID, REASON_ID

The entities in play are thus the two main entities: *Location* and *Reason*, and their join table entity: *LocationReason*.

Previously, when the project was running **Grails 2.2.3** and everything worked just fine, the *LocationReason* domain class looked like this:

**LocationReason.groovy**

```
class LocationReason implements Serializable {
    Location location
    Reason reason

    static belongsTo = [Location, Reason]

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['location', 'reason']
        version false
        table 'location_reason'
    }

    static constraints = {
        location blank: false
        reason unique: ["location"], blank: false
    }

    def getPK() {
        ["locationId":location.id, "reasonId":reason.id]
    }

    String toString() {
        reason.description + " at " + location.description
    }
}
```

I have been upgrading to **Grails 2.4.5** (and hence had to upgrade the version of Hibernate as well), and am now getting the following error when calling the built-in *save* method:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "REASON_1_"."ID": invalid identifier
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
at edu.liberty.swiper.LocationReasonController.save(LocationReasonController.groovy:48)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.java:59)
at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:100)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I turn on SQL logging, this is the query that's being generated:

**Hibernate-generated query**

```
select this_.location_id as location1_19_0_, this_.reason_id as reason2_19_0_ 
from location_reason this_ 
where reason_1_.id=? and this_.location_id=?
```

To preface, ALL other sql operations for this and other entities are successful. I can insert, update, delete on all other entities, and can delete *LocationReason* entities (update is not applicable), but **only inserting *LocationReason* fails**.

If you'll notice, the generated query aliases the *location_reason* table as *this_*, and subsequently uses it for each field in the SELECT clause... but then only for the *location_id* field of the WHERE clause. The *reason_1_1* prefix on the other field in the WHERE clause completely baffles me. 
Hibernate didn't join to the *Reason* table and alias it as *reason_1_1*; in fact, it's completely invalid for the query. Additionally, Hibernate knew to use *reason_id* in the SELECT clause, but then suddenly uses just *id* in the WHERE clause, which makes no sense. 
Additionally, I see no difference in my configuration for the *Location* entity vs the *Reason* entity, so why is the SQL correct for the *location_id*, but not for the *reason_id*?

On a sidenote, I was a little surprised to see a SELECT statement instead of an INSERT, but I guess Hibernate is first checking to see if it already exists before doing so.

I have since looked into various ways to represent the relationship (I relied heavily on the GORM documentaion for Grails 2.4.5 [here](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys)) and make sure that the columns are specified as being *location_id* and *reason_id*, but **the result is the same error every single time**. For reference, here is the current version of the class, and I have tried virtually every combination of GORM config between what's here and what's commented out:

**LocationReason.groovy** (Updated)

```
class LocationReason implements Serializable {

    Location location
    Reason reason

//    static belongsTo = [Location, Reason]

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['location', 'reason']
        table 'location_reason'
//        location(column: 'location_id')
//        reason(column: 'reason_id')
        columns {
            reason {
                column name: 'reason_id'
            }
            location {
                column name: 'location_id'
            }
        }
//        location insertable: false, updateable: false
//        reason insertable: false, updateable: false
        version false
    }

// Excluding constraints, getPK, and toString as they are the same as above

    @Override
    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof LocationReason)) {
            return false
        }

        other.reason == reason && other.location == location
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append reason
        builder.append location
        builder.toHashCode()
    }
}
```

Perhaps the issue is that there's just something Hibernate doesn't like about the Reason class, so I've included some GORM information for both Location and Reason below:

**Location.groovy**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes=["description"])
class Location implements Comparable<Location>{
    String description
    Integer capacity = 1000
    String username

    static hasMany = [reasons: Reason]

    static mapping = {
        sort description:"asc"
        id generator:'native', params:[sequence:'MY_SCHEMA.ID_SEQ']
        version false
        reasons joinTable: [name: 'LOCATION_REASON', key: 'LOCATION_ID', column: 'REASON_ID'], cascade: 'none', join: 'fetch'
    }

    static constraints = {
        description unique: true, blank: false, maxSize: 64
        capacity nullable: true
        username maxSize: 30
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

**Reason.groovy**

```
class Reason implements DataSourceSpecificRule {
    String description
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    String username
    ReasonEvaluatorSource reasonEvaluatorSource

    static belongsTo = [Location]

    static hasMany = [locations: Location]

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'native', params:[sequence:'MY_SCHEMA.ID_SEQ']
        startDate column: 'START_DATE'
        endDate column: 'END_DATE'
        reasonEvaluatorSource column: 'REASON_SOURCE_ID'
        locations joinTable: [name: 'LOCATION_REASON', key: 'REASON_ID', column: 'LOCATION_ID'], cascade: 'none'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        description unique: true, maxSize: 128
        startDate nullable: true
        endDate nullable: true
        username maxSize: 30
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

For reference, *DataSourceSpecificRule* is an interface that defines some getter and setter methods it expects implementing domain classes to have, such as *getId* and *setId*.

For completeness' sake, here are the relevant parts of my BuildConfig that changed with the Grails upgrade:

**BuildConfig.groovy (Pre-upgrade, Grails 2.2.3)**

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    build ':release:2.2.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3'

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    compile ":db-reverse-engineer:0.5"
    compile ":rest:0.7"
}
```

**BuildConfig.groovy (Post-upgrade, Grails 2.4.5)**

```
grails.servlet.version = '3.0'
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
grails.project.source.level = 1.8

plugins {
    runtime ':jquery:1.11.1'
    runtime ':resources:1.2.14'
    runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.18'

    build ':tomcat:8.0.30'
    build ':release:3.1.2', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3'

    compile ':cache:1.1.6'
    compile ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5'
    compile ':rest:0.8'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2'
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas and/or help!

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't figured out why the built-in save does not work (I'm convinced it's a bug in either GORM or Hibernate, and/or an incompatibility with some other plugin or dependency I'm using), but I did come up with a workaround using JDBCTemplate, which comes pre-loaded with Grails.

So if anyone finds themself in the same pickle, you can utilize the JDBCTemplate by first adding the bean in resources.groovy

**/configuration/spring/resources.groovy:**

```
jdbcTemplate(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate, ref('dataSource'))
```

where *dataSource* is the name of the database source bean you're using for this GORM object.

Next you'll need to create a service where you'll use the JDBCTemplate. I chose to make a LocationReasonService

**/services/LocationReasonService.groovy:**

```
//package info omitted 

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

class LocationReasonService {
    // Grails will autowire the jdbcTemplate by name into this variable
    def jdbcTemplate

    @Transactional
    def save(LocationReason locationReason) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("insert into location_reason (location_id, reason_id) values (?, ?)", 
            locationReason?.location?.id, locationReason?.reason?.id)
    }
}
```

Then configure the controller to use this service:

**/controllers/LocationReasonController.groovy:**

```
//package and imports omitted
class LocationReasonController {
    // Grails will autowire the service by name into this variable
    def locationReasonService

    // other fields and methods omitted

    def save() {
        def locationReasonInstance = new LocationReason(params)
        // The built-in GORM save used to work in grails 2.2.3, but there seems to be a bug in 2.4.5 that breaks on saving this particular entity
//        if (!locationReasonInstance.save(flush: true)) { 
        if(!locationReasonService.save(locationReasonInstance)) {
            render(view: 'create', model: [locationReasonInstance: locationReasonInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
            message(code: 'locationReason.label', default: 'LocationReason'),
            locationReasonInstance
        ])
        redirect(action: 'show', params: locationReasonInstance.getPK())
    }
}
```